# UK Business Visa Application Refused. How can I rectify my mistake?

Tags: visas, uk

I have applied for a business visit visa for training in the UK at one of our suppliers.

I have already provided the invitation letter from my UK sponsor company and also the sponsorship letter from my Saudi Arabia employer.

And I also provide my personal bank statement.

What documents do I need to provide to satisfy the visa officer ?

[image]

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the letter that they wanted your bank statements **in English**.  So providing that would be a good start.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge First Of all thanks for your reply ,i will provide that in new application but my company transfer me 2000 GBP for this trip and it will be shown in my bank statement. and my salary which i stated in the letter from the Employer not credited in a good pattern because my employer some time not give salary for two months and some time he transfer for two months according to business circumstances. I am raising this question as i read recently many refusal cases and their replies.How can i justify my current statement in a good manner?

Comment: If your employer makes irregular payments to you, then you'll need documentation from them explaining why they did that.

Comment: A letter From Employer Stating That they make delayed salary Payments & Sometime sum up the salary of two months at a time is enough to proof myself?  @CMaster

Comment: Submitting documents that have not been translated is pretty much an open and shut case that you didn't read the guidance. You are inviting another refusal on some new grounds unless you totally read the guidance. It's really the answer to your question!

Comment: @GayotFow   I am going re-apply with new Documents i.e  Invitation letter from UK Organization,Sponsorship letter from Employer ,Salary details and Bank Statement Clarification letter from Employer Verifying the un-Sequential Salary credited to my Account and Stating that they have credited 2000 GBP In my Account on --- Date For UK Visit And Translated Personal Bank Statement. Is there any more things required according to refusal ???

Comment: @CMaster first of all thanks for all the answers, these answers really help me a lot. As it is stated in the refusal that " if granted Leave to enter you will abide by all the conditions attached to any such leave and that you will leave the UK on Completion of the proposed Visit". What should i provide to Satisfy the Visa officer that i will leave the UK at the end of propsed visit of 4 days, As i am already attached letter from my current employer stated that i am full-time employee of the company and he approves my leave for the proposed visit.

Comment: @CMaster and i will return after this visit to Saudi Arabia to join my job Again immediate after the end of Visit.As i am stated in the application that i am single & have no dependents . Please Advice in this regard .

Answer (score 4):

Your application has been refused in this particular case, because when going to assess whether you had sufficent means to support yourself during the trip, the ECO notice that your bank statements were (partly) in Arabic. As all documents are required to have an English translation, they stopped assessing you there.

Obviously any new application will have to submit these documents translated. As you can see from the comments and other questions on this site, you should explain (with evidence) any irregular payments in to your account, especially large ones.

You should also be aware that there may be more reasons your inital application would be refused - it was just that the untranslated statement was a show stopper, so no further assessment took place.

You should consult the offical [UK government site](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/tourist-short-stay-visas) and understand what is required and what the decision is being made on (UK visas are not a purely box checking exercise - providing all the required paperwork is only part of it, your paperwork **also** has to give evidence that you will leave when you say you will, not attempt to break the terms of your visa and can support yourself while in the UK).

Comment: first of all thanks for all the answers, these answers really help me a lot. As it is stated in the refusal that " if granted Leave to enter you will abide by all the conditions attached to any such leave and that you will leave the UK on Completion of the proposed Visit". What should i provide to Satisfy the Visa officer that i will leave the UK at the end of propsed visit of 4 days, As i am already attached letter from my current employer stated that i am full-time employee of the company and he approves my leave for the proposed visit.

Comment: and i will return after this visit to Saudi Arabia to join my job Again immediate after the end of Visit.As i am stated in the application that i am single & have no dependents . Please Advice in this regard .